# how foldr works on this data tree?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I know how foldr works on Leaf, but I don't know how foldr work on Node. What is the parameter \x z' if we already have f and z as parameter. assume we have

```
tree = Node [Leaf 1, Leaf 2, Node [Leaf 1, Leaf 3]]
```

how this code works

```
foldr (+) 0 tree
```

```
data RoseTree a =  Leaf a | Node [RoseTree a] 
instance Foldable RoseTree where 
    foldr f z (Leaf x) = f x z
    foldr f z (Node ns) = 
        foldr (\x z' -> foldr f z' x) z ns
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can discuss the implementation with your given sample data:

```
foldr (+) 0 (Node [Leaf 1, Leaf 2, Node [Leaf 1, Leaf 3]])
```

We here thus have a `Node`, so we take the second clause so we replace this with:

```
foldr (\x z' -> foldr (+) z' x) 0 [Leaf 1, Leaf 2, Node [Leaf 1, Leaf 3]]
```

The outer `foldr` thus works on the list, which means that, by the [documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/GHC-List.html#v:foldr):

> ```
> foldr f z [x1, x2, ..., xn] == x1 `f` (x2 `f` ... (xn `f` z)...)
> ```

So that means that the above `foldr` is replaced with:

```
foldr (+) (foldr (+) (foldr (+) 0 (Node [Leaf 1, Leaf 3])) (Leaf 2)) (Leaf 1)
```

So the outer function is now `foldr (+) (...) (Leaf 1)`, this is the first clause of our `foldr` definition, so that is equal to:

```
(+) 1 (foldr (+) (foldr (+) 0 (Node [Leaf 1, Leaf 3])) (Leaf 2))
```

We then can evalate the `foldr (+) (...) (Leaf 2)` expression, which is handled in the same way:

```
(+) 1 ((+) 2 (foldr (+) 0 (Node [Leaf 1, Leaf 3])))
```

or less verbose:

```
1 + 2 + foldr (+) 0 (Node [Leaf 1, Leaf 3])
```

Then finally we again have a `foldr (+) 0` that works on a `Node`, this thus again results in an evaluation as discussed above:

```
1 + 2 + foldr (+) (foldr (+) 0 (Leaf 3)) (Leaf 1)
```

We thus can again evaluate the outer `foldr (+)` to:

```
1 + 2 + (+) 1 (foldr (+) 0 (Leaf 3))
```

and the inner `foldr (+)` to:

```
1 + 2 + (+) 1 ((+) 3 0)
```

or less verbose:

```
1 + 2 + 1 + 3 + 0
```

which is equivalent to:

```
7
```

which is the sum of the nodes in the `Leaf`s.

It is important to note that the outer *`foldr`* (here denoted in *italics*), is not the same `foldr` function as the inner **`foldr`** (here denoted in **boldface**) in the implementation: the outer one works with a list as functor, whereas the inner one is the one we define in the `instance Foldable RoseTree`:

```
instance Foldable RoseTree where 
    foldr f z (Leaf x) = f x z
    foldr f z (Node ns) = foldr (\x z' -> foldr f z' x) z ns
```

In case we thus perform a `foldr` on a `Tree` with a function `f` and an initial value `z`, we will replace all leaves with `f x z`, (so for `foldr (+) 0` that is `(+) x 0`, or `x + 0`).

The `Node`s will result in *folding* the values together where the result of the fold of the tailing elements is used as initial value of the fold with the head element.

Answer (score 6):

The definition of `foldr` for `Node` calls `foldr` on the list of `RoseTree`s. Then, inside of that `foldr`, it calls `foldr` on each subtree, using the current accumulator as the initial parameter.

Basically, even though it looks like the function calls `foldr` twice, it is calling it for different types each time, and so only one is recursive. The other is the `foldr` defined for `[a]`.